# How do i pass command line parameter in a simple WIX msi?

Tags: wix

msiexec /i myproduct.msi LANG=1.

I dont have a bootstraper project, i have wix project with simple Product.wxs file.If lang=1, i dont want to execute level 3 feature. Based on the lang parameter i am trying to set a variable to set registery value to be written to HKLM or HKCU

```
 <Feature Id="ProductFeature"  Level="1">
      <Condition  Level="2">LANG=1</Condition>
      <Condition  Level="3">LANG=0</Condition>
      <Feature Id="MyFeatureBHJ" Title="My Feature BGJ" Level="2">
          <?define DllRegLocationGj = "HKCU" ?>
          <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />          
      </Feature>
      <Feature Id="MyFeatureBHJttgj" Title="My Feature BjjGJ" Level="3">
        <?define DllRegLocationGj = "HKLM" ?>
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />            
      </Feature>
 </Feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know which registry entry you need at runtime, why don't you move the nested features ("MyFeatureBHJ" and "MyFeatureBHJttgj") out of your parent feature "ProductFeature"? Then just pass the feature name directly via command line?

```
msiexec /i install.msi ADDLOCAL= ProductFeature ,MyFeatureBHJ

or 

msiexec /i install.msi ADDLOCAL= ProductFeature , MyFeatureBHJttgj
```

Update: So ideally your Feature element will look like this:

```
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature"  Level="1">             
              <!--All components list goes here-->
     </Feature>
    <Feature Id="MyFeatureBHJ" Title="My Feature BGJ" Level="1">
              <!--Component specific to feature BHJ-->          
    </Feature>
    <Feature Id="MyFeatureBHJttgj" Title="My Feature BjjGJ" Level="1">
              <!--Component specific to feature BHJttgj-->          
    </Feature>
```

Comment: When i do above, actually all features are getting installed.For example msiexec /i install.msi ADDLOCAL= ProductFeature ,MyFeatureBHJ

Comment: Did you move the nested features ("MyFeatureBHJ" and "MyFeatureBHJttgj") out of your parent feature "ProductFeature"?

Comment: Check the update, your feature list should look something like that. Then you should tell which all features you want either 1 &2 or 1 & 3 using the ADDLOCAL property.

Comment: Thanks,it should work.When we dont use command line and do regular install,is anyway to skip feature "MyFeatureBHJ"?Is to put a level higher than 1000 is the solution to skip?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct,your answer should work,thanks.But in my case, when i pass in command line to install feature "U",  the variable it set is HKLM instead of HKCU

msiexec /i OfficeAddInSetup.msi ADDLOCAL="U"

```
  <Feature Id="U" Title="Excel Add-in" Level="1">
   <?define DllRegLocationGj = "HKCU" ?>
    <ComponentRef Id="ExcelRegistry_FriendlyName_HKCU" />       
  </Feature>  

  <Feature Id="L" Title="Excel Add-in" Level="1">
   <?define DllRegLocationGj = "HKLM" ?>
    <ComponentRef Id="ExcelRegistry_FriendlyName_HKLM" />       
  </Feature>

      <Component Id="ExcelRegistry_FriendlyName_HKCU">
        <RegistryValue Id="ExcelRegistry_FriendlyName_HKCU" Root="$(var.DllRegLocationGj)"
                       Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddIns\ExcelAddIn"
                       Name="FriendlyName"
                       Value=ExcelAddIn"
                       Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>



      <Component Id="ExcelRegistry_FriendlyName_HKLM">
        <RegistryValue Id="ExcelRegistry_FriendlyName_HKLM" Root="$(var.DllRegLocationGj)"
                       Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddIns\ExcelAddIn"
                       Name="FriendlyName"
                       Value="ExcelAddIn"
                       Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
      </Component>
```